# convert querystring in asp.net 4,0

Tags: asp.net, query-string

i wanna convert querystring like :

`product.aspx?productID=12345` to `12345.aspx`

is there a way to do a convertion like that... if you can help i ll be greatfull...
thx...

Comment: It is called `UrlRewriting`. Google or search here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to look onto URL ReWriting
[tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the IIS URL Rewrite extension: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite